# How do I get a responsive tooltip & sticky header (mobile-friendly)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, sticky

I have created an HTML table with a header row that contains tooltips. Unfortunately, the tooltips get cut off when I scroll down in the table. How do I fix this? Also, they should be responsive, but only turn up at the top instead of popping up where it is optimal.

Also, I want to keep this header row sticky (also on mobile) so that when people scroll, the header is always visible.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table class=my_table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th height="42" rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="164">
   <div><strong><span style="color:#000000;">Financial Product</span></strong></div>
   </th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="149"><strong><span style="color:#000000;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="A best-case scenario is the optimal outcome. It helps to assess the potential profit you can make by investing in the product.">Best Case</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="112"><strong><span style="color:#000000;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="A worst-case scenario is the least favourable outcome. It helps to assess the potential loss you can make by investing in the product.">Worst Case</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="150"><strong><span style="color:#000000;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="Prices as of right now.">Prices (in $)</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;" width="120"><strong><span style="color:#229954;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="For instance, the underlying can be one or multiple company shares, an index such as the German DAX®, a precious metal such as gold, or a commodity such as oil.">Underlyings</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="71"><strong><span style="color:#229954;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="A price cheaper than the market rate. For instance, if the market rate is $50 and the product trades at $45, then it trades at a discount.">Discount</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="100"><strong><span style="color:#229954;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="A barrier event (% of stock price) works as protection. For instance, if the stock price is $50 and the barrier event is 80%, then the initial investment is paid back only if the stock price never touched $40 (80% x $50). If that price is reached until maturity, the payoff depends on the performance of the worst performing underlying.">Barrier<br />
   Event</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="67"><strong><span style="color:#229954;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="Usually, when structured products trade at a discount, their upside (the potential gain) is capped. For instance, if they trade at $45 instead of $50 (10% discount), the maximum payout is limited to $56.">Capped (in $)</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="99"><strong><span style="color:#229954;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="Structured products also have participation rates that describe an investor's share in the return of the underlying assets. Participation rates below 100% mean that the investor will realize a return that is less than the return on the underlying assets.">Participation</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="157"><strong><span style="color:#229954;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="A coupon payment is guaranteed unless in brackets. Then, it is only paid out if the barrier event did not take place. A coupon payment is the annual interest rate you receive.">(Conditional) Coupon</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;" width="100"><strong><span style="color:#229954;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="A bonus is paid only if the barrier event is not reached. It can be described as a one-time payment you receive.">Bonus (in $)</abbr></span></strong></th>
   <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;" width="135"><strong><span style="color:#229954;"><abbr rel="tooltip" title="Some Structured Products offer 100% protection of the initial investment and others offer partial or no capital protection. In case your capital is 100% protected, then you get back all your invested money if the underlying is performing poorly.">Capital Protection</abbr></span></strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center;">
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 1</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">6.25%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-10.51%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 2</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">3.73%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-13.60%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 3</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">11.36%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-7.28%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 4</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">6.51%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-13.61%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 5</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">4.27%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-23.30%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 6</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">5.21%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-22.33%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 7</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">9.66%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-20.19%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 8</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">1.78%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-31.08%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 9</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">18.64%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-8.63%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Stock 10</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">14.85%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-14.40%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP1</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">5.65%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-14.00%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">45</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">Yes</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">56</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP2</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">13.20%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-37.39%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">30</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">Yes</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">110%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP3</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">5.68%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-15.92%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">No</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">85%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">5.8%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP4</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">12.61%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-11.32%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">No</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">53%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:11px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>50<span style="font-size:11px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP5</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">8.32%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-23.91%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">No</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">88%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">9%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP6</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">8.90%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-35.00%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">No</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">85%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">9.12%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP7</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">11.59%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-53.77%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">No</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">60%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">16%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP8</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">16.47%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-42.95%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">No</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">55%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">6.40%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP9</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">4.65%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-8.77%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">4</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">No</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">100%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">95%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="21" style="text-align: center;"><strong>SP10</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">19.32%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">-36.32%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">50</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">5</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">No</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">85%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">100%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">0.6% (+2.3%)</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">100%</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>

<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
#tooltip
{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #111;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 15px;
    width: max-content; 
    max-width: 200px;
}
 
    #tooltip:after /* triangle decoration */
    {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-top: 10px solid #111;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: -10px;
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
 
        #tooltip.top:after
        {
            border-top-color: transparent;
            border-bottom: 10px solid #111;
            top: -20px;
            bottom: auto;
        }
 
        #tooltip.left:after
        {
            left: 10px;
            margin: 0;
        }
 
        #tooltip.right:after
        {
            right: 10px;
            left: auto;
            margin: 0;
        }

table.my_table {
  font-size: 11px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

table.my_table td, table.my_table th {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid 1px;
}

table.my_table th {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

And here is my JS Code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    var targets = jQuery( '[rel~=tooltip]' ),
        target  = false,
        tooltip = false,
        title   = false;
 
    targets.bind( 'mouseenter', function()
    {
        target  = jQuery( this );
        tip     = target.attr( 'title' );
        tooltip = jQuery( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );
 
        if( !tip || tip == '' )
            return false;
 
        target.removeAttr( 'title' );
        tooltip.css( 'opacity', 0 )
               .html( tip )
               .appendTo( 'body' );
 
        var init_tooltip = function()
        {
            if( jQuery( window ).width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5 )
                tooltip.css( 'max-width', $( window ).width() / 2 );
            else
                tooltip.css( 'max-width', 200 );
 
            var pos_left = target.offset().left + ( target.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 ),
                pos_top  = target.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20;
 
            if( pos_left < 0 )
            {
                pos_left = target.offset().left + target.outerWidth() / 2 - 20;
                tooltip.addClass( 'left' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'left' );
 
            if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > jQuery( window ).width() )
            {
                pos_left = target.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + target.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;
                tooltip.addClass( 'right' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'right' );
 
            if( pos_top < 0 )
            {
                var pos_top  = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight();
                tooltip.addClass( 'top' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'top' );
 
            tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } )
                   .animate( { top: '+=10', opacity: 1 }, 50 );
        };
 
        init_tooltip();
        jQuery( window ).resize( init_tooltip );
 
        var remove_tooltip = function()
        {
            tooltip.animate( { top: '-=10', opacity: 0 }, 50, function()
            {
                jQuery( this ).remove();
            });
 
            target.attr( 'title', tip );
        };
 
        target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
        tooltip.bind( 'click', remove_tooltip );
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the HTML for the table?

Comment: Sorry, I will add it!